# What does it show on Google Analytics data if someone visits my website from the Facebook app?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook

As per my Google Analytics data, most people on my website come from:

```
m.facebook.com / referral
```

Are these people coming to the website from the Facebook iOS/Android app or m.facebook.com or both?

Comment: I believe they are coming from both. The in app has a browser which is simply a webview which is sourced at `m.facebook.com`. Keep in mind there are also link shims for referrals including `lm.facebook.com` which has something to do with HTTPS. I don't want to put this is as the actual answer though because I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

They come from anything Google considers a mobile device. You can see device specific info in the analytics pane- more info here https://blog.kissmetrics.com/what-analytics-is-hiding/

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics interprets the FB App as a visit from the FB mobile site...so it should register in your analytics visitor activity as a visitor coming from m.facebook.com